# How to sent mails in windows server

Tags: windows, sendmail, iis-8

I am having my html template with two contact form. I am bit confused how can i make the mail functions in windows server. 
Currently my client running with windows server supported by IIS v8.0 and he is not ready to install php to his server . 
Smtp is also turned on now .
Can any let me know how can i make mail function works in windows server.

Comment: You're serving static HTML from the server? No ASP.NET?

Comment: yes its a static html from server , just once the form is submitted just email sent to my client is more enough

Comment: use classic asp posting the form to the asp file and sending mail. You might wanna check if asp is enabled(it is already installed u just have to enable it.) .
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/754136/Send-Email-using-Classic-ASP